# Is it possible to add apex:inputFile dynamically to the DOM during runtime with Javascript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, dom, apexinputfile

I can add html elements to the DOM but how do I add a VF element such as apex:inputFile?

From this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56126/how-do-i-dynamically-add-input-fields-on-a-visualforce-page) I understand that I can use a wrapper class and apex:repeat but I was wondering if there is another approach for this.

Since I can't [reference a variable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/58591/38518) from the running class Via JS Remoting, the Rendered attribute is not an option.

Comment: Best you explain what you are trying to do overall. `apex:...` tags have both a client and server side part and changing the DOM can only address the client side.

Answer (score 0):

[apex:dynamicComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dynamicComponent.htm) component allows to push component definition from server side based on some programming logic. You can use this to create `apex:inputFile` at runtime and push to client.